# Wire Connector For Heated Blanket

Tags: electrical

So for Christmas I got my wife a king size heated blanket.  She absolutely loved it.  Unfortunately a two weeks ago we also got a new dog and it started using the cord as a chew toy.  What would be the best way to repair this connection? Ideally I would like to cut all four wires and reconnect them but I am not sure what voltage they are carrying.  The wires appear to be 16-18 awg if that helps[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd inline splice & solder it, then heatshrink.

Use some heat shrink tubing, spread the wire enough to hold the heat shrink.
inline wrap the wire to its mating side so that it stays flush in the lengthwise of the wire, then solder it.
Then heat shrink each over the repair.

This will reudce the likelyhood it pulls apart, keeps out moisture, and is electrically safe.

This is not 100% how I explained it, but google inline splice wire, and you will see numerous pictures to get the idea:
https://www.instructables.com/id/Soldering-Tutorial-Inline-Splicing/

Comment: Our new dog from a shelter is lovable but a chewer. He chewed the cord of a plugged in heating pad  down to the conductors, but fortunately he chewed between the inline switch and the pad and the switch was off. I plan to do what @nobyman suggests, but haven't yet.

Comment: What will you do to prevent recurrence?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg Jim Steve, while certainly outside of home improvement, definitely try various toys to find something your dog loves to chew MORE, and be sure to crate your dog when not home (but not as a punishment!), give them plenty of attention without long hours away, and when home, dilligently train them to NOT chew on the non toys. Dogs old and young can learn new tricks. Good luck. (You can try a dog repellent spray on some items but I'd opt for the former)